# Configure FileMaker Pro OBDC data source administrator

Tags: odbc, filemaker

I have a database created by someone else in FileMaker and I was trying to connect it to QGIS.

As a newbie, I was looking around and found out I could do it passing throught the ODBC.

I installed FileMaker 19 64bit and the ODBC Client also 64bit.

Following this [guide](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/15/en/fm15_odbc_jdbc_guide.pdf) I found on FileMaker website, I started the configuration of the Microsoft ODBC Data Source Administrator 64bit, as the database is on my pc, I set the `Host` as `localhost`.
But when I was trying to test the FileMaker DSN Configuration first I obtain this window:

[image]

but I am not sure what this `User ID` and `Password` are... the database I have doesn't have any user or password.

Then if I click `OK`, I obtain this message:

[image]

Looking around it seems to be a problem related to the firewall, even if everything is local, and I set new inbound and outboud rules for the port 2399 following this [steps](https://support.claris.com/s/article/Configuring-Windows-and-OS-X-firewalls-for-FileMaker-Server-1503693091220?language=en_US), but this didn't solve the problem.
I used `Port Query` to check the port and the status is `NOT LISTENING`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I found the user and password in the FileMaker `File Options..`, in this way I could connect the DSN.